# Why does .load() Work in Chrome & Edge but NOT Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to dynamically load audio files into a page and have this code:

```
<script>
var audio369 = '/owners/1/images/customers/369.mp3';
$('#audio369 audio source').attr('src', audio369);
$('#audio369 audio')[0].load();
</script>
```

And my HTML

```
<div id="audio369" style="position:relative;width:30%;margin:1em 
auto;display:inline-block;min-height:30px;">
<audio controls >
<source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>
```

My page works great in Chrome and Edge, but in Firefox the div #audio369 only appears after opening Developer tools. Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

[peter.certifiedtransmission.com](http://peter.certifiedtransmission.com)

Comment: Any console errors in FF?

Comment: Happy firefox users...As for me, any unexpected sound on a web-page makes me hate and close it. Sound should only be played on a web-site when it is absolutely required and asked by user: "pronounce" button for dictionary website, "use sound" for recaptcha, "play music" for online radio etc.

Comment: Yeldar, with all due respect there is not "unexpected sound(s)" on my webpage. Rather, the audio files are for use as customer audio reviews that are played by site visitors upon their initiation to do so.I am attempting to load the files via jquery to optimize page load speed. I did not see any obvious errors in the console. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out changing the width of the audio container which was 30% to a minimum of 50% fixed the issue. No clue why this would matter but that is and if anyone can shed some light great. Thanks.